# Do ruins have any effect in Freeciv?

Tags: freeciv

When a city is destroyed, there will be ruins on the tile formerly occupied by the city. I could remove the ruins by pillaging it, but will there be any material impact on the game if I choose not to remove the ruins? What exactly is the use of ruins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all built-in rulesets that have ruins, ruins have no effect on gameplay.

> Ruins mark the former site of a city that was destroyed or abandoned. They have no effect on gameplay.

Reference: [data/classic/terrain.ruleset](https://github.com/freeciv/freeciv/blob/R2_6_5/data/classic/terrain.ruleset#L1474-L1477)